# Is there a way to tell if you're still hidden in the fog of war?

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes you see players in competitve play stand in the middle of a lane but the enemy doesn't notice them. Or When players gank from odd entrances. 
Is there a way to know if you're still in the dark? (not applying the presence of wards)

Comment: No, but one way to tell if the enemy can see you in a bush is that the minions will try to hit you, and your character will auto-attack something if it's in range.

Answer (score 3):

after playing from a while you get a "feel" of what they can see in lane; unless it is warded somewhere they dont know. From my experience, it's intuition. Like when you gank through lane and sneak into the bush, you usually watch for the closest minion. I think the radius of the minions are like 700 or something like that

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to see that you're covered by the fog of war by your enemies perspective or not. Most of what you see is intuition based on how the enemy you see is reacting to you. If they are noticeably avoiding the bush or they're glowing (With a slight yellow outline) because they have targeted you it usually means you are being seen. If someone is standing in the middle of the lane unnoticed is because they're on the lookout for another champ or waiting for the minions waves.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see how whether or not they minions can see you while you are on the very edge of the jungle is to see if there is a piece of the Fog Of War between you and the lane. If there is then that means that the minions can't see you, and it's pretty likely champions can't either.